# Per-Proxy Authentication in Java

Tags: java, http, authentication, proxy, socks

I am trying to support authenticated proxies in my Java application. My understanding that the java.net.Proxy class does not support authentication, and you need to handle authentication yourself.

I have created a subclass of the java.net.Proxy class, that takes two additional parameters, username and password.

Implementing HTTP proxy authentication was quite easy, and the method getHttpProxyAuthenticationHeader simply returns the base64 encoded auth info, to pass to HttpUrlConnection or similar.

I'm having trouble with Sock proxies though. I cannot find any documentation on sending authentication to a Socks server. I'm unsure if I need to implement the SOCKS authentication protocol in my class using a method such as authenticateSocksProxy(OutputStream stream), and then call

```
authedProxy.authenticateSocksProxy(outputstream);
```

before using the socket like

```
outputstream.writeBytes(myData.getBytes());
```

Another option would be to return a byte[] of the authentication data and then write the data manually, instead of the class writing the authentication data.

I do not think the java.net.Authenticator, or System.setProperty methods  will be of any use, since my implementation needs to work on a per-connection basis and be thread-safe.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was taken from JSocks project sources:
https://code.google.com/p/jsocks-mirror/source/browse/trunk/src/java/net/sourceforge/jsocks/socks/UserPasswordAuthentication.java

I think it's clean enough to understand full process:

```
 /**
  SOCKS5 User Password authentication scheme.
*/
public class UserPasswordAuthentication implements Authentication{

   /**SOCKS ID for User/Password authentication method*/
   public final static int METHOD_ID = 2;

   String userName, password;
   byte[] request;

   /**
     Create an instance of UserPasswordAuthentication.
     @param userName User Name to send to SOCKS server.
     @param password Password to send to SOCKS server.
   */
   public UserPasswordAuthentication(String userName,String password){
     this.userName = userName;
     this.password = password;
     formRequest();
   }
   /** Get the user name.
   @return User name.
   */
   public String getUser(){
     return userName;
   }
   /** Get password
   @return Password
   */
   public String getPassword(){
     return password;
   }
   /**
    Does User/Password authentication as defined in rfc1929.
    @return An array containnig in, out streams, or null if authentication
    fails.
   */
   public Object[] doSocksAuthentication(int methodId,
                                         java.net.Socket proxySocket)
                   throws java.io.IOException{

      if(methodId != METHOD_ID) return null;

      java.io.InputStream in = proxySocket.getInputStream();
      java.io.OutputStream out = proxySocket.getOutputStream();

      out.write(request);
      int version = in.read();
      if(version < 0) return null; //Server closed connection
      int status = in.read();
      if(status != 0) return null; //Server closed connection, or auth failed.

      return new Object[] {in,out};
   }

//Private methods
//////////////////

/** Convert UserName password in to binary form, ready to be send to server*/
   private void formRequest(){
      byte[] user_bytes = userName.getBytes();
      byte[] password_bytes = password.getBytes();

      request = new byte[3+user_bytes.length+password_bytes.length];
      request[0] = (byte) 1; 
      request[1] = (byte) user_bytes.length;
      System.arraycopy(user_bytes,0,request,2,user_bytes.length);
      request[2+user_bytes.length] = (byte) password_bytes.length;
      System.arraycopy(password_bytes,0,
                       request,3+user_bytes.length,password_bytes.length);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I could not find any info on the SOCKS spec to implement something like this.